# Как сделать, чтобы одна Activity передавала данные в lIstView в другой Activity?

Tags: java, android, listview, activity, android-intent

Я уже несколько дней пытаюсь сделать мини-приложение, но совсем запуталась.
У меня есть 2 Activity, в первой ListView и кнопка создать привычку. Когда нажимаете на кнопку, вы переходите во вторую Activity, в которой 2 EditText: title(название привычки) и description (описание привычки).Когда нажимаете на кнопку сохранить и  на стрелку, то возвращаетесь назад, теперь ListView показывает только название привычки, которую только что сохранили. Сам вопрос состоит в том, как сделать, чтобы  ListView показывал только название привычек, но кликая по ним, эмулятор переходил во 2 Activity и показывал сохраненные название и описание именно для этой привычки.

(Я сделала каждую привычку как отдельный объект класса HabitClass.java, но не уверена, что это правильно). Мой код на данный момент.

1 Activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<String> habitStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView addIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow_icon);
        addIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateHabit.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.mygoalsandhabits", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("TitleSet", null);
        if (set != null) {
            habitStringArray = new ArrayList(set);
        } else {
            habitStringArray.add("Read a book");
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.habit_list);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, habitStringArray);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateHabit.class);
                intent.putExtra("habitId", position);  
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2 Activity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CreateHabit extends AppCompatActivity {
    HabitClass habitClassObject;
    public static ArrayList<HabitClass> habitArray = new ArrayList<>();
    int habitId;
    String title, descr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_habit);

        EditText edTxtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_txt_title);
        EditText edTxtDescr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_txt_descr);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        habitId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);
        if (habitId != -1) {
            habitClassObject = habitArray.get(habitId);
            title = habitClassObject.getTitle();
            descr = habitClassObject.getDescr();
            edTxtTitle.setText(title);
            edTxtDescr.setText(descr);
        }
        TextView saveBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save_txt);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                title = edTxtTitle.getText().toString();
                descr = edTxtDescr.getText().toString();
                habitClassObject = new HabitClass(title, descr);
                MainActivity.habitStringArray.add(habitClassObject.title);
                habitArray.add(habitClassObject);
                MainActivity.habitStringArray.add(title);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.notes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

HabitClass.java:

```
package com.example.mygoalsandhabits;

public class HabitClass {
    String title;
    String descr;

    public HabitClass(String title1, String descr1) {
        this.descr = descr;
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getDescr() {
        return descr;
    }

    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно передавать данные из одной активности в другую через доп. параметры intent. Для этого используется intent.putExtra() или intent.putInt() (putString(), putBundle() и т.д.). В принимающей активности нужно читать эти данные из интента через intent.getExtra. Это у вас сделано. Но дальше идёт ошибка. Список habitArray у вас пустой во второй активности, поэтому прочитать оттуда нельзя. Да и смысла передавать всю коллекцию нет (есть шанс уронить приложение по достижению 1 Мб памяти при передаче из одной активности в другую). Поэтому передавать надо не весь список, а один элемент.

Чтобы получить обратно новые данные из второй активности в первую, можно использовать onActivityResult, правда, он deprecated, см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative и https://habr.com/ru/company/e-Legion/blog/545934/.

Можно использовать ViewModel, но это сложнее, требуется архитектура MVVM. Также можно писать напрямую в SharedPreferences во второй активности и потом читать оттуда данные из первой. Можно использовать БД, тогда достаточно читать и писать данные прямо в активности, а передавать позицию в списке, как у вас сейчас. Способов много, на самом деле.

Comment: Я хотела сделать через SharedPreferences. Мне для названия привычки надо создавать одну переменную SharedPreferences titlePrefs, а для описания другую SharedPreferences descrPrefs?

Comment: Я уже пробовала делать чтобы, одна активность просто передавала данные другой, но каждый раз возвращаясь в 1 активность у меня создавалась копия привычки из которой я только что вышла.

Comment: @Мария Для того чтобы сохранить и прочитать данные из SharedPreferences, нужна сериализация. Проще всего сделать её с помощью Gson (преобразует список в JSON-строку): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872280/2914140. Ну или поищите другие способы. Можно двумя списками, но это неудобно, да и синхронизация страдает.

Comment: После возврата из второй активности в первую вам необходимо вызвать коллбэк. Раньше это делалось через `onActivityResult`, сейчас схожим образом. В коллбэке вы узнаете результат операции (успешно или ошибка, как запрограммируете), если нужно. И получите там новые данные.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Мария, о, вы так быстро разобрались! Приятно слышать.